# What can I do when my laptop keyboard starts to die?

Tags: keyboard, laptop-repair

I have a key on my built-in keyboard that is starting to die. What can I do to:

- downright fix it
- make it better
- make it easier to type

Any other hints?

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by `is starting to die`? Does it randomly work when you press it, does it need to be pushed in harder, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Clean your keyboard. Sometimes a tiny piece of dust may prevent a good key from being pressed normally.
2. Remap your keyboard. On Windows you can use [Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx). On Linux you can use xmodmap. This way you will be able to enter symbols from the broken key using another key.
3. Use an external keyboard.
4. Buy a new laptop keyboard. They are [not expensive](http://www.google.com/products?num=20&hl=en&q=laptop+parts+keyboard), and with care you can even replace it yourself (if you don't have guarantee anymore; unfortunately, laptops are not easy to open). Otherwise, visit a service center.